# How to have borders, font styles etc using MailApp.sendEmail Google Spreadsheet Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, jakarta-mail, border-layout

Is it possible for **MailApp.sendEmail** command to send to a receipient that has a body message that looks like this?

[image]

Basically I want my message to be in written and arranged with borders. Anyone who could advise? Thanks advance!

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of creating the right html to use for the content of the message?  [This guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) will help you determine what css to use to format your message.